# Proxy Error: Could not proxy request /api/admin/login from localhost:8080 to http://127.0.0.1:3333 (ECONNRESET) with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, adonis.js

I am trying to make call from vuejs project to adonis js using proxy. My vue.config.js file is as bellow:

```
devServer: {
      proxy: {
            '^/api': {
              target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3333',
              secure: false,
              changeOrigin: true,
              pathRewrite: {
                '^/api': '/api'
              }, 
              logLevel: 'debug',
              headers: { 
                Connection: 'keep-alive'
             },
            }
           }
         },
```

This configuration is working when I am trying to login with wrong credential, then backend adonis project is returning properly. But when I am trying with correct credentials, It throws this message:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/admin/login from
> localhost:8080 to http://127.0.0.1:3333. See
> https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for
> more information (ECONNRESET).

I have tried in many different ways by changing proxy configuration, but it is not solved yet. If need any more information, feel free to ask.